# Persisting object does not persist all its relational objects

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am have three entities with relations look like this:

- Customer and Order: one-to-many
- Order and Article: one-to-many

Here are my Java Classes:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Order implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
    private Customer customer;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
    private List<Article> orderedArticles;
}

@Entity
@Table
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    private List<Order> orders;
}

@Entity
@Table
public class Article implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "article_id")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
    private Order order;
}
```

And then I persist the order to the database:

```
Customer customer = createCustomer()
List<Article> articles = createArticles();
Order order = new Order(customer, articles)
entityManager.persist(order);
```

The order and customer were successfully persisted but strangely that the article not. Can anyone help me here what did i do wrong? How can I make one call to persist the order and parallel the customer and article will be also persisted?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try change

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
private List<Article> orderedArticles;
```

to

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Article> orderedArticles;
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your suggesstion. I did as you suggested but got an exception:
11:07:00,065 INFO : insert into customer (customer_id) values (?)
11:07:00,070 INFO : insert into order (customer_id, order_id) values (?, ?)
11:07:00,076 INFO : insert into article (order_id, article_id) values (?, ?)
11:07:00,078 WARN  SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23502
11:07:00,078 ERROR: null value in column "order_id" violates not-null constraint. Detail: Failing row contains (3, null).

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Maybe caused by `Article.Order.orderId` is null, sorry, I'm not sure about this, maybe you should persist order first, then get the order ID and set that into Article.

Answer (score 0):

1. As it mentioned in this [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/):

> Cascading only makes sense for *Parent – Child* associations (the *Parent* entity state transition being cascaded to its Child entities). Cascading from Child to Parent is not very useful and usually, it’s a mapping code smell.

So, for example your *Order - Article* association should be corrected in this way:

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class Order implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Article> orderedArticles;
}

@Entity
@Table
public class Article implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne // CascadeType.ALL should not be used here
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
    private Order order;
}
```

The same correction should be made for the *Customer - Order* association.

2. You use [bidirectional](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional) `@OneToMany`. So, as documentation states:

> Whenever a bidirectional association is formed, the application developer must make sure both sides are in-sync at all times.

For example your `Order` entity should have the following methods:

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class Order implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Article> orderedArticles;

    public void addArticle(Article article) {
        orderedArticles.add(article);
        article.setOrder(this);
    }

    public void removeArticle(Article article) {
        orderedArticles.remove(article);
        article.setOrder(null);
    }
}
```

to make the bidirectional association *Order - Article* in-sync. The same correction should be made for the *Customer - Order* association.

---

Assuming that your `Order` and `Customer` entities have the appropriate helper methods, the valid example of persisting can look like this:

```java
  Article article1 = new Article();
  // ...
  Article article2 = new Article();
  // ...

  Order order = new Order();
  order.addArticle(article1);
  order.addArticle(article2);

  Customer customer = new Customer();
  customer.addOrder(order);
  
  entityManager.persist(customer);
```

So, you should start from articles creation, then add them to the order (or orders), then add your order (or orders) to the customer entity and then `persist` the customer. Due to the usage of  `CascadeType.ALL` all children entities will be persisted too.

Comment: Hi SternK, thank you for your answer. I did like you suggested. This means before I persisted the order I called the addArticle() on order and addOrder on customer: 
Customer customer = createCustomer();
List<Article> articles = createArticles();
Order order = new Order(customer, articles);
order.addArticle(article);
customer.addOrder(order);
entityManager.persist(order);

But I still got an  exception: Attempting to save one or more entities that have a non-nullable association with an unsaved transient entity. 

It seems that the persist's order is important. Do you have any idea?